# How to get the index of a table

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to get the index name to automate a DataStore script

This is the table, how would I get the "Points" part?

```
local List = {
    ["Points"] = 0
}
```

Edit: Nevermind, I figured it out. It's just the "i" part in

```
for i, v in pairs(List) do
    local Local = Instance.new("IntValue",leaderstats)
    Local.Name = i
end
```

Comment: Use `List["Points"]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved your problem, but for those who still don't know, when we work with the `pairs(table)` function in a loop, two variables are passed:

knowing that tables work as follows:

```lua
[key] = value
```

the loop:

```lua
for k, v in pairs(table) do
     print(k, v)
end
```

`k` will collect all **keys** from the table, while `v` will collect all **values** from the table, one by one for each sequence of the loop